# Como puedo agregar una clase a un li sino la tiene o eliminarla si la tiene

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Estoy agregando unos elementos

dinámicamente mediante Jquery a una página cada vez que le doy clic al botón.

Tengo en el archivo de css la siguiente clase:

```
ul li.marked {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que si le doy clic a un li y no tiene la clase marked la agregue y lo contrario, si la tiene, eliminarla, creo que debería usar addClass y removeClass, pero no lo tengo muy claro como debería usar ese condicional para verificar si el elemento tiene o no la clase y hacer lo respectivo según el caso.

---

### style.css

```
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;

  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
```

}

```
ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
```

}

```
ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3; 
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li.marked {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

button#add {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
```

}

---

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nuevos elementos</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <h3>Elementos:</h3>
      <ul class="elements">
      </ul>
      <button id="add">Agregar elemento</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### app.js

```
// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#add').click(function(){
       insertarElemento();
   });

    function insertarElemento() {
    $('.elements').append('<li>Elemento ' + ($(".elements li").length));
  }
});
```

El efecto al agregarle la clase al li es como de tachado y se difumina el color del texto, ya eso está definido en la regla de css.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usa `.toggleClass()`

Comment: @derloopkat, como puedo referenciar a que li se le está haciendo clic?

Comment: la etiqueta que recibe el evento click es `this` y al hacer `$(this)` obtienes un objecto jQuery. para asi poder llamar al metodo toggleClass.

Comment: Te recomiendo que aprendas a usar el editor de snippets de Stack Overflow ([puedes leer más en este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). Los consejos que encontrarás allí, harán que tus preguntas sean más fáciles de leer, tu código y errores más fácil de reproducir, y por lo tanto, ayudarías a que la gente te pueda responder mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo `toggleClass()` de jquery. Lo que hace es agregar la clase si existe, de lo contrario la elimina:

```js
// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#add').click(function(){
       insertarElemento();
   });
   

   // aqui definimos el evento sobre los li creados
   $(".elements").on("click", "li", function(){
    // agregamos o eliminamos la clase del elemento
     $(this).toggleClass("marked")
   });
    function insertarElemento() 
    {
      $('.elements').append('<li>Elemento ' + ($(".elements li").length));
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;

  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3; 
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li.marked {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

button#add {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nuevos elementos</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <h3>Elementos:</h3>
      <ul class="elements">
      </ul>
      <button id="add">Agregar elemento</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```